# MS Visual Studio 2017 - Adding image to MS SQL Azure hosted DB via query in MS 2017

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I've struggled to find an exact solution, and it feels like the specifics here are the cause/solution.  I have a MS Azure hosted SQL database with a table dbo.users and it has a column called profilePic.  I'm just testing form layouts right now so don't need the upload form functionality, so I'm just trying to slap some images into the DB to pull on.  Searching online has given me the following SQL:

```
update dbo.Users
set profilePic = BulkColumn 
from Openrowset (Bulk 'C:\Users\tezfi\Pictures\FTS.png', Single_Blob) as Image
where userID = 1;
```

but when I run this I get the following error:

```
Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\Users\tezfi\Pictures\FTS.png" could not be opened. Operating system error code (null).
```

I'm guessing it's because there's a DB user on the Azure portal trying to access my PC, but how do I grant this access?

Comment: Please see my answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959338/error-executing-openrowset-bulk-azure-sql-database/46959744#46959744

Comment: In addition, as you can read in this Microsoft Documentation, OPENROWSET is not supported on Azure SQL Database.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql