# Azure SQL database - Right approach to get content of a file in store procedure

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2017

** Scenario:**

- SQL stored procedure takes fileName as input.
- Read the content of the file and insert it into a table.

For local SQL server, above scenario has been achieved by following stored procedure.

```
-- @_filePath would be input to the store procedure
DECLARE @_filePath NVARCHAR(MAX) =  'C:\SQLContent\test1.sql'

CREATE TABLE tmpTable (tmpIndex INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, sqlContent NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL)

-- Read content of the file @_filePath
DECLARE @_insertQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'insert tmpTable (sqlContent) select * from OPENROWSET(bulk ''' + @_filePath + ''', SINGLE_CLOB) as a'
EXEC sp_ExecuteSql @_insertQuery


Select * from tmpTable
```

**Problem:**

The actual problem is with Azure SQL server, a path provided in above-mentioned stored procedure won't be accessible to SQL server.

> C:\SQLContent\test1.sql

*Error Message with SQL Azure:*

> Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\SQLContent\test1.sql" could not be opened. Operating system
>   error code (null).

**Possible Solutions:**

1. Upload file test1.sql to Azure blob and in the stored procedure read file content from the blob as follows:

> ```
> select *
> from OPENROWSET
>  (BULK 'temp1.sql', DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureStorage', SINGLE_CLOB) as data
> ```

Reference - [[error executing OPENROWSET (BULK) / Azure SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959338/error-executing-openrowset-bulk-azure-sql-database][1])

2. Instead of passing @_filePath as an argument to the stored procedure, pass file content as an argument to the stored procedure.

**Ask**

Out of two possible solutions to the problem, which one is the best one and why?

Also, Suggest if there is any other better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OPENROWSET or you can use BULK INSERT also. I don't know any advantage or disadvantage that can make one better than the other. However, if the storage account is public you need as a minimum to create an external data source:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
 WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE, LOCATION = 'https://myazureblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net');

BULK INSERT Product
FROM 'data/product.dat'
WITH ( DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorageAccount');
```

If the storage account is not public you need to create a database scoped credential additionally.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyAzureBlobStorageCredential
 WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
 SECRET = 'sv=2015-12-11&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rwac&se=2017-02-01T00:55:34Z&st=2016-12-29T16:55:34Z&spr=https&sig=copyFromAzurePortal';

​CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
 WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
        LOCATION = 'https://myazureblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net',
        CREDENTIAL= MyAzureBlobStorageCredential);

BULK INSERT Product
FROM 'data/product.dat'
WITH ( DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorageAccount');
```

Hope this helps.